# Read from a file and count the words in a list

Tags: c#

I am using C# to read a csv file and spit all the words in new lines. Then I want to count how many times each word in that file got repeated in the list. The output that I get is not counting the words. please see the below information

csv file content:
She is nice
he can be nice
oh wow this is great

This is the code :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = File.ReadAllLines("Try3.csv");
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("Try3.csv"))

        { 
            string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
            foreach (string part in parts)
            {

                var q = list.GroupBy(x => x)
                    .Select(g => new {Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
                    .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count);
                foreach (var x in q){
                Console.WriteLine("{0}",part+" Count:"+ x.Count);
        }


    }
    }   
  }
   }
```

This is the output I got:

[[image: output]]

Any idea please?

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn [how to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  For starters, why are you splitting the string into words and then running a grouping operation for every word?

Comment: I hate to be pedantic, but that is not a CSV file, it's simple text. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var results = File.ReadLines("Try3.cvs")
                  .SelectMany(line => line.Split(' '))
                  .GrooupBy(word => word)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

First using `File.ReadLines` will mean you only read in one line at a time instead of loading the entire file into memory before processing.  This can be helpful if the file size is large.  Then it's just a simple matter of splitting the lines into words then grouping on those words to create a dictionary that will have the words at the key and the number of times it showed up in the file as the value.

To get the results in order by the count you could opt to do the following instead.

```
var results = File.ReadLines("Try3.cvs")
                  .SelectMany(line => line.Split(' '))
                  .GrooupBy(word => word)
                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                  .Select(g => new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: This seems identical to his code other than you used a `Dictionary<K,V>` rather than an anonymous object?  And you left out the ordering.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Well for starters this doesn't read the entire file in twice.  Also it will actually result in a key-value pair of word and count.

Comment: No you're right, the key here is you took out the unnecessary `foreach` on the `parts`, sorry I had to re-read his code a few times. :)

Comment: You should add in his `OrderByDescending` just to be complete.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Since I went with creating a dictionary, ordering shouldn't matter.  But since the OP does use it then a list of word-count might make more sense.